# Multiply the occurence of each element in a list by 4

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to achieve the following scenario.

[image]

I have an `oldList` and I am trying to multiply the occurences of each element by 4 and put them in a `newList` by using the Stream API. The size of the oldList is not known and each time, it may appear with a different size.

I have already solved this problem with two traditional loops as follows;

```
private List< Integer > mapHourlyToQuarterlyBased( final List< Integer > oldList )
{

   List< Integer > newList = new ArrayList<>();

   for( Integer integer : oldList )
   {
      for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
      {
       newList.add( integer );
      }
   }

   return newList;
}
```

but I have learnt the Stream API newly and would like to use it to consolidate my knowledge.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use a `flatMap` to produce a `Stream` of 4 elements from each element of the original `List` and then generate a single `Stream` of all these elements.

```
List<Integer> mapHourlyToQuarterlyBased =
    oldList.stream()
           .flatMap(i -> Collections.nCopies(4, i).stream())
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Very nice use of `Collections` there Eran

Answer (score 10):

You can acheive that using `flatMap`:

```
List<Integer> result = list.stream().flatMap(i -> Stream.of(i,i,i,i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or in a more generic way:

```
List<Integer> result = list.stream().flatMap(i -> Stream.generate(() -> i).limit(4)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For each element in the input list, this creates a stream consisting of this element repeated 4 times and flat maps it. All the elements are then collected into a list.